# Color to Bitmap

Tags: c#, image, graphics, bitmap, pixel

How do I go about setting a Bitmap with a `Color` of the pixels. I created a program with `LockBits` and it is very fast but now I need to set a `PictureBox` with that image I ran through the `LockBits` I do not want to use SetPixels My current code is:

```
Bitmap imageFile = new Bitmap(bmpPath);

BitmapData imageData = imageFile.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, imageFile.Width, imageFile.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

IntPtr Pointer = imageData.Scan0;

int ArraySize = Math.Abs(imageData.Stride) * imageFile.Height;

byte[] PixelArray = new byte[ArraySize];

Marshal.Copy(Pointer, PixelArray, 0, ArraySize);

int PixelAmount = 4; //ArGb

Color ArGBformat;

Bitmap RenderedImage = new Bitmap(imageFile.Width, imageFile.Height);

byte NewAlpha;
byte NewRed;
byte NewGreen;
byte NewBlue;
unsafe
 {
  for (int y = 0; y < imageData.Height; y++)
   {
       byte* row = (byte*)imageData.Scan0 + (y * imageData.Stride);

       for (int x = 0; x < imageData.Width; x++)
        {
             int offSet = x * PixelAmount;
             // read pixels
             byte blue = row[offSet];

             byte green = row[offSet + 1];

             byte red = row[offSet + 2];

             byte alpha = row[offSet + 3];

             //Manipulates pixels
            NewAlpha = Convert.ToByte(Math.Abs(alpha - _Alpha));
            NewRed = Convert.ToByte(Math.Abs(red - _Red));
            NewBlue = Convert.ToByte(Math.Abs(blue - _Blue));
            NewGreen = Convert.ToByte(Math.Abs(green - _Green));


           ArGBformat = Color.FromArgb(NewAlpha, NewRed, NewGreen, NewBlue);

           RenderedImage.SetPixel(x, y, ArGBformat); //Slow and want something else
       }
   }
 }
```

I would like to set my `PictureBox1` to the pixels that get ran through the program.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer. I needed to set the pixels back.

```
//Sets image
row[offSet] = NewBlue;
row[offSet + 1] = NewGreen;
row[offSet + 2] = NewRed;
row[offSet + 3] = NewAlpha;
```